# Sphinx search with optional params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I want to use search with optional params (Thinking Sphinx).

In my controller I have 3 params:

```
params[:model_id], params[:engine_id], params[:city_id]
```

Controller

```
  def search  
    @search = Car.search :conditions => {
      :model_id => params[:model_id],
      :engine_id => params[:engine_id],
      :city_id => params[:city_id]
      }
  end
```

Model

```
define_index do
    indexes model_id
    indexes city_id
    indexes area_id
    indexes engine_id
    indexes mileage
  end
```

When one of parameters is nil, I get an error:

Extracted source (around line #4):

```
1: Result:
2: %br
3: %br
4:   = render :partial => "search_item", :collection => @search, :as => :item

index car_core: syntax error, unexpected TOK_FIELDLIMIT near '  @engine_id  @city_id'
```

UPD1:

My Form

```
= form_tag search_adverts_path, :method => :get, :id => 'admin_quick_filter' do
  %label
    = t('form.mileage')
  = text_field_tag :min_mileage, params[:min_mileage]
  = text_field_tag :max_mileage, params[:max_mileage]
  %br
  = select_tag :model_id, options_for_select(Model.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]} , params[:model_id]), :include_blank => true
  %br
  = select_tag :engine_id, options_for_select(Engine.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]} , params[:engine_id]), :include_blank => true
  %br
  = select_tag :city_id, options_for_select(City.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]} , params[:city_id]), :include_blank => true
  %br
  %br
  = submit_tag t('form.search')


= render "search_result"
```

Comment: Maybe I should use sphinx_scope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define_index do
  indexes name

  has mileage
end
```

Car.search :with => {:mileage => 100..150000}

Worked

Answer (score 1):

While searching, when you provide `:conditions`, ThinkingSphinx appends @filedname in your query to scope search to that field. And sphinx does not deal with `nil values`. So  you should check for nil values before passing it to the `search()` method.

> Please keep in mind that Sphinx does not support SQL comparison
>   operators – it has its own query language. The :conditions option must
>   be a hash, with each key a field and **each value a string**.